# titulo/index no pandas

Tags: python, pandas, índices

bom dia a todos, tenho uma planilha no python e estou com uma dúvida, como faço para adicionar uma escrita emcima do meu index? por exemplo
tenho meu df
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
emcima de descrição, como faço para adicionar um texto(que seria uma informação adicional que quero escrever), quero que ele faça parte do meu index, pois na hora que eu executo o meu código, todas as páginas exibem o index, então por isso quero que seja uma informação do index.
essa é minha duvida!!!

Answer (score -2):

O index de um DataFrame Pandas é uma Series, que pode, opcionalmente, ter um nome (name). No caso apresentado, esse nome é "Descrição".
Se vc pretende exibir o DataFrame de uma forma personalizada, terá de criar uma forma sua, particular, para tal.
Ou então, até mesmo, criar uma classe inteiramente personalizada.